# How to deploy nodejs code from local machine to google app engine

Tags: node.js, git, google-app-engine

I have just started with nodejs and app engine. I am following the tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/tutorials

1) I have created a project then cloned the `nodejs-mvms-quickstart` repository.

2) Opened `Development/source code` and opened the `nodejs-mvms-quickstart/1-hello-world`

3) and started the node server

```
npm start
```

This is working fine. Now I want to deploy my nodejs application from my local server without copying to github and cloning on the server.

For this I am using following command

```
gcloud app deploy
```

but this is showing following errors:

```
If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Building and pushing image for service [default]
WARNING: No node version specified.  Please add your node version, see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines
Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones.
You may also view the gcloud log file, found at
[C:\Users\Sunil Garg\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2017.05.07\20.38.59.221000.log]
.
Started cloud build [1cd2979e-527b-4d68-b430-31471534246e].
To see logs in the Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/1c
d2979e-527b-4d68-b430-31471534246e?project=help-coin
ERROR: gcloud crashed (error): [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly
 closed by the remote host

If you would like to report this issue,please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems,please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myapp",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "connect-timeout": "^1.8.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "generic-pool": "^2.4.2",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "requestify": "^0.1.17"
  }
}
```

What is the issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: can you post your package.json

Comment: @KalanaDemel updated my question

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following 2 parameters to the package.json

Add the version of node your application is compatible with.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "4.6.0"
    }
```

since you're using `npm start` you might need this in the script parameter as well since npm start is calling command stated in start in script param, change `app.js` according your application, like `node quickstart.js`. Always make sure to specify the path if your package.json is in the root directory and the `.js` is in a sub directory as well.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js"
}
```